# Over 550 processes shown in Activity Monitor

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

I'm running High Sierra on my older iMac. I opened Activity Monitor and clicked on the Memory tab to temporarily monitor the Memory Pressure. The memory pressure was fine but I noticed Activity Monitor listed over 550 processes. Is this a reasonable number for a single user machine? If not, what should I do about this?

Comment: ummm how did you count them?

Comment: i counted the first 50 and counted how many lines of similar size there was in the list.  Just scrolled down till thw bottom.

Comment: using the comment by @klanomath i get 497 processes so i overcounted by about 50!

Comment: I have with  10.14.5 Safari(6 tabs) and Xcode(~1gig source files), 422 processes but I don't see how can this question continue to be.. cc: @klanomath I won too ;p

Comment: MacbookPro on Mojave and 4 apps open (+finder) and I have at LEAST that many

Comment: The CPU tab gives a processes count, bottom right - mine says 518, so I'm not far behind you. I am currently using about 38GB of 64GB RAM, but only 3% CPU, so I'm not worried anything's amiss.